# Act 4 hell uniques problems

Tags: diablo-ii

I am playing a single player meteorb sorceress and I can not complete Act 4 on hell. To access Diablo, you need to kill 3 uniques, Infector of Souls, Lord de Seis and Grand Vizier of Chaos. Now, I have faced them two times already, and both times they were immune to both fire and cold. My defensive merc from nightmare act 2 cannot deal with them either, since they heal faster than he damages them (or at least Infector of Souls does). I tried hiring the lighting merc from Act 3, with no success.

So, what do I do? Is there are chance that they spawn differently, not immune to both fire and cold?

**EDIT** Well, having watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfOHUsTweNU) video, I realized that the way to go is just to save and exit and try again. It's not necessary that the uniques have both resistances, it's random. I got lucky on the fourth time :)

Comment: I believe those immunities are preset, but I'd need to research that to be certain

Comment: You can see some stats here: http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Superuniques#Grand_Vizier_of_Chaos

Comment: If those stats are correct, only one is cold immune.

Comment: You are playing on Single Player, not just online by yourself? If you were on the ladder, you could make an Infinity rune word.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/40817/108003

Comment: @DCShannon This is single player, no ladder. The solution is simple however.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at some more stuff later, and it looks like they have some set resistances, and then additional random ones on top, which may stack to create an immunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention, the immunities can vary and "rerolling" the monsters can result in better options.

The Infector of Souls in Hell has base elemental resistances (see [d2wiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Infector_of_Souls%20*here*)) 150% Fire, 70% Cold, 95% Lightning.  So he'll always be Fire Immune.  Each game, the various bosses get randomly assigned modifiers.  The Infector always gets  "Spectral Hit" and  "Extra Fast" and in Hell, he gets two additional randomly-selected modifiers.  If one of those is "Cold Enhanced", that boosts his cold resists by 75% ([see d2wiki](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Monster_modifier))which puts them to be more than 100% so he would be also Cold Immune, which is a problem for Meteorb builds unless they have a really strong merc.  It sounds like that or something comparable happened the first time you tried.

Another option is to carry a wand with Lower Resist charges to remove immunities, but depending upon how high the resists are, that may not work.  The expensive ladder-only "Infinity" runeword gives the Conviction aura, which can also break some immunities (and increase damage dramatically for nearly immune monsters.)

You may have better luck with a Might Act 2 merc (offensive from Nightmare) rather than a Defensive merc.  With a decent weapon, that may be better and you should be able to Static Field them to halfway to help your merc along.

Comment: In Hell, The Infector is always Fire Immune, the Grand Vizier is also always Fire Immune, and Lord De Seis is always cold immune.  De Seis' base fire resists are 75% so if he gets a modifier which improves fire resists, he can be dual immune cold/fire, which sounds like that happened in your first effort as well.