# Javazon Hell Mode stuck in the jungle

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm playing javazon and i'm stuck in act 3 spider forest and flayer jungle with hundreds of  lightning immunes little monsters. I tried buying teleport staff but it is still hard, is there any other way to pass through the jungle aside from teleporting your way from the docks to lower kurast?

I mostly play single player and all I can think of is joining a party.

Comment: Are there any online tutorials you've tried to follow already that were less than helpful?

Comment: You can always run like crazy with a big train chasing you until you reach a waypoint.

Comment: To be very fair, the Lightning immune Fetishes can be absolutely brutal if you're not geared/ready for it. If you need more help, I'd need to know what gear/level/skills/stats you're working with and what is happening, I'm assuming it's just the Fetishes killing you but could also be the Souls.

Comment: Actually (it's been 20 years since I played this game so memory is fuzzy), I remember making a Javazon that had melee spear as backup plan. Next to no skills in it, just enough to deal with immune critters.

Comment: Fast boots, and other faster run equipment. Use teleport strategically, to get out of being cornered, or take shortcuts. Get lots of FHR so you don't get stuck and swarmed. Invest in a lot of Vitality. And as amazon, make use of Decoy/Valkyrie/Slow missiles etc in your passive tree. A decoy can be very useful to get past monsters. Don't try to kill monsters, just get past them and do the objective you need.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to explore the Spider Forest and Flayer Jungle.

The Spider Forest has the Spider Cavern which contains Khalim's Eye and the Flayer Jungle has the Flayer Dungeon which contains Khalim's Brain.

## Mobility

Amazons have very poor [Faster Cast Rate](https://www.purediablo.com/diablo-2/breakpoints/#Faster_Cast_Rate) (FCR) making quickly teleporting around difficult. Having a teleport staff to get over a wall every now and then will be beneficial, but teleporting around without a decent amount of FCR will be difficult.

I would instead suggest grabbing some Faster Run/Walk boots and instead invest in Faster Hit Recovery (FHR) which will minimize how long you are stunned when you take more than 1/12th your character's maximum health.

## Dealing with Monster Immunities

You can either deal multiple types of damage to work around monster immunities, break a monster immunity by lowering their resists or just ignore the monster!

For Javazons in particular, you have 3 main forms of damage, physical, Lightning and poison. You can use Jab for some good physical damage, Charged Strike/Lightning Fury for Lightning damage and Poison Javelin for some poison damage. Truthfully, Physical/Lightning should be good for most scenarios.

If you're determined to only do Lightning damage, then you can shop a lower resist wand from Drogan in Act 2 Nightmare/Hell or grab something like an Infinity. More details can be found here: [What is the best way to deal with creatures that are immune to you in Diablo 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40817)

MrLlamaSC has a full walkthrough guide and specifically goes into detail for Javazon Act 3 here:

Comment: Worth noting: Infinity is a Ladder-only runeword. Don't try and make it if you're not playing on the ladder as all you'll accomplish is wasting some very high level runes.

Comment: This is not true in Diablo 2 Resurrected, Ladder-Only runewords are now available in both SP and MP.
Community Manager Hooley explains: "We wanted to take this opportunity to share that Ladder Only Rune Words, Unique Items, and Horadric Cube Recipes that were once restricted to Ladder rank play will now for the first time be included in non-ladder multiplayer and single-player play.